# SPOJ - Life, the Universe, and Everything

Tags: c

I dont understand why they are not accepting this as the solution,They are saying its a wrong answer:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    int val=0;
    printf("Input:- \n");

    do {
        scanf("%d",&val);
        printf("%d \n",val);
    }
    while(val < 42);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might be a surprise, but not every one does know what "SPOJ ..." refers to (except for a tribute to Douglas Noël Adams). So, please complete your question with **all** relevant information.

Comment: Reading the answers and comments, your program gives the correct output (apart from the cue) for the example given on the SPOJ problem definition, because you print `88` and then stop because `88` is not less than `42`. But you have not read the problem statement carefully enough, and your submission will be tested by SPOJ with a *different* sequence of numbers to the example. http://www.spoj.com/problems/TEST/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two mistakes:

1. Remove this line- `printf("Input:- \n");`
2. In question you have to print before coming 42. If 42 has come you have to break.

Like this:

```
if(n!=42) 
   printf("%d\n",n); 
else 
   break;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the problem statement states that you should keep on printing numbers until 42 arrives.

1)what if the first number is 42 itself?Your code is going to print it anyway

2)`printf("Input:- \n");` remove this line.This is provided just to show what the input is.You don't have to print this.

3)`while(val<42)` `val` can be anything other than `42` not necessarily less than `42`

A good way is to try some of your own testcases and compare the output with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Why are any number above 42 not allowed? Use a `while(1)` and break when `42`.
This question has already been answered at [Life, the Universe, and Everything](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38008/life-the-universe-and-everything)

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the problem to when input is 42 or greater you have to stop processing but the problem is actually when input is exact 42 stop processing.
Despite of the fact what you understand  you have one flaw in your code that when input is 42 you will print it first then your do while loop will end.