# SPOJ Life Universe and Everything

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to solve the below problem on spoj with Java6(JAR):-

Your program is to use the brute-force approach in order to find the Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything. More precisely... rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of one or two digits.

Input:
1
2
88
42
99

Output:
1
2
88

SPOJ is not accepting my solution.I think the below solution has some error. If not, Is there ant special format to write the code on spoj so that my solution will get accepted.

```
 import java.util.*;

   class Life
  {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int arr[] = new int[100];
int a;

for( a=0;a<100;a++)
{
  int i = sc.nextInt();
  if(i<100)
  {
  arr[a]=i;
  }

  if(a>0)
  {
  if(arr[a-1] > arr[a])
  break;

  }
 }

  for(int j=0;j<a;j++)
  {
  System.out.print(arr[j]);
  }

  sc.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that there are only 100 elements from the input?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SPOJ - Life, the Universe, and Everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208964/spoj-life-the-universe-and-everything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't understand problem statement perfectly! It is like you have infinite input as integer but stop when you get the input as `42` till that print all the integers you get as an input. So here is the code for it!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Life
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true)                 //This loop will always run till we break it from inside the loop
        {
            int ip=sc.nextInt();    //Taking input as an integer
            if(ip == 42)            //If input is 42 , break the loop
                break;
            System.out.println(ip); //else print that integer and continue the loop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it also says Stop processing input when you get 42, not stop processing output, so are you supposed to output 42 as the last output item?

Comment: No at the input 42 , you should stop taking input so no need to print 42 as last output. Simply break the loop at input 42.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted Solution of above problem

```
 import java.util.*;
        import java.lang.*;

        class Main
        {
            public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
            {
                ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList();
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                while(scanner.hasNext()){
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                    if(num>=0 && num<100){
                    if(num == 42){
                        break;
                    }
                    arrayList.add(num);
                    }
                }
                Iterator itr = arrayList.iterator();
                while(itr.hasNext()){
                    System.out.println(itr.next());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Java Solution

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    if (sc.hasNext())
    {
    while(true)
        {
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        if (n==42)
        {
            break;
        } 
        System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
}
```